# how to use user defined variables in file path concatenation using shell script

Tags: linux

```
$var='system1'

data=C:/data/$var/current_extract/*
```

> Output should be 
>       data=C:/data/system1/current_extract/*"

```
but i still see the result C:/data/$var/current_extract/*  $var value is 
**system1** not showing the path
```

Comment: `$var=` --> `var=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting a variable in **Linux** `variable_name=value`. For displaying it you have to prefix the variable name with `$` symbol. for example `echo $variable_name`

```
var='system1'
data=C:/data/$var/current_extract/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dollar in the assignment

```
var='system1'
```